# Insert HREF into SQL HTML Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hyperlink, html-table

I'm trying to dynamically generate a link in an XML structured table but I get the HREF printed as text in the td that is generated.

```
  DECLARE @HTML_LinkInTable nvarchar(MAX)


SELECT @HTML_LinkInTable =
                  '<table>' + 
                  '<tr>' +
                  '<th> Link Example </th>' +
                  '</tr>' +               
                  CAST(( SELECT 
                  (SELECT '<a href="http://exampleurl.com/' + CONVERT(varchar(15),ET.Command) + '">View</a>' as 'td' for xml path(''), type)
    FROM 
        dbo.ExampleTable ET     
FOR XML path('tr'), ELEMENTS) as nvarchar(MAX)) +
                  '</table>'
```

The cell values are `'<a href="http://exampleurl.com/GoGoGadgetCopter'">View</a>'`

instead of [View](http://#)

Comment: change your speech marks " into single quote marks '

Comment: producing same result as before

Comment: can you go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and enter some sample data and replicate this issue please so i can see what youre working with and see how i can help you out.

Comment: i would test on my own machine but im in the middle of dropping from win10 to 8.1

Comment: What frontend technology are you using to fetch data and display it as HTML